# how to pass object in webview.invokescriptasync windows 8.1

Tags: html, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, windows-8.1, winjs

I need to pass one object from my App to webviews html page.
I know we can invoke function of webview's page uusing invokescriptasync and also pass data as parameter. but it takes only string as parameter.

object which I want to pass cannot be serialized. so I need to pass it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

The app and the Webview run in isolated script contexts, thus you are limited to passing information as string properties of the args object given to invokeScriptAsync. This is by design for security reasons, with no means to bypass it; otherwise you open the potential for malicious code in a Webview to directly modify app objects.